# Is it OK to retag questions when the sequel is released?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the [fifa-14 tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fifa-14) and noticed that the oldest question goes all the way back to October 2012. I thought this was a bit early so I looked at the edit history and noticed the tag had been recently updated from fifa-13 to fifa-14.

Here is the question: [2 player on same computer FIFA 13 online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/90209/12813)

Now in this case the question is still relevant, and the answer may also be correct - or at least close enough to be helpful.

So, is this kind of thing ok? Should the original fifa-13 tag have remained too?

Furthermore, does this effect who "created" the tag? (which I believe was me). Will this change who gets the "Taxonomist" badge? (not that I expect to get that on a Fifa game anyway)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No - this shouldn't have happened. However, the edit was made by the original user so I'm suspecting that what they actually intended to do was ask the same question for a later release of the game. To clarify this would require input from the user in question.

As for whether this retag should be rolled back - yes, in my opinion. The edit is far later than the answer, the answer is accepted, the question is protected, the correct solution would be to rollback the tag edit and have the user re-ask the question for the new game.

The taxonomist badge is awarded to the user who created the tag - in the instance that the first question in a tag later has that tag removed but the tag still exists because it has other questions, that user is still responsible for creating that tag.

Comment: I was just going to post something like this and then you answered first. You ninja.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected to be the case but have never seen or dealt with it to be sure so I wanted to clarify before taking any action (which you have already done anyway)

Answer (score -1):

Once a question has been answered, **no**, I don't think the game (tag) should be changed *even if* the game is a sequel and the answer is still correct, *especially* in cases where we don't even know if it is. If the question *has not been answered*, then I think it's okay to edit it to be the sequel.

The one who first edited a tag into a question or posted a question with a tag (even if the question was later removed or the tag edited out) is responsible for creating the tag.

Comment: I think the tag should *never* be edited to a sequel, the original question still stands. Even if it never got an answer. That would be like deleting a question because it got no answers and a sequel has been produced. (For example [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96664/is-gaining-vehicle-skills-affected-at-all-by-pulling-off-risky-manoeuvres)).